# OpenGL ES textures are all black

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I create 8 textures through:

```
GLuint textures[8];
glGenTextures(8, textures);
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image0%d", i + 1];

    CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t kwidth = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t kheight = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);

    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(kwidth*kheight*4, sizeof(GLubyte));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, kwidth, kheight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

But get all black textures:

[image]

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(kwidth*kheight*4, sizeof(GLubyte));
```

Creates a GLubyte array filled with zeros. Since you never modify `spriteData` anywhere, the textures are filled with zeros which is black.

Comment: Thanks, I'm so stupid that I delete ` CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, kwidth, kheight, 8, kwidth*4, CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
        
        CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, kwidth, kheight), spriteImage);
        
        CGContextRelease(spriteContext);`.